# How does the CSS cascade algorithm work with tailwind classes?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, css-cascade

I was having a look at the [tailwind-merge](https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge/blob/v1.12.0/docs/what-is-it-for.md#what-is-it-for) and realized that because of the CSS cascade some tailwind classes cannot be overridden once applied.

example: [tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/brsE2f6aDz)

```html
<div class="grid h-screen place-content-center bg-red-100">
  <div class="w-80 bg-red-300 py-8 px-8 p-2">Content</div>
</div>
```

The `p-2` class cannot override the `py-8 px-8` classes, no matter in what order we put them, and the same happens with [this example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ONtSyF92l8)

```html
<div class="grid h-screen place-content-center bg-red-100">
  <div class="w-80 bg-red-300 px-8 px-20">Content</div>
</div>
```

I went thru the [CSS Cascade documentation at mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade) but I still cannot quite get it.

Can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: All three of `py-8`, `px-8`and `p-2` apply their values via rules that have the same _specificity_, so the rule that comes last in stylesheet order, wins.

Comment: Here is a great link to learn more about [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Why do you expect `padding: 0.5rem` to override the more specific `padding-top: 2rem;`?

Comment: @Gabe I don't think that's what specificity stands for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @CBroe, thanks a lot for your comment. If you want to turn it into an answer (like I did here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76365930/47633) I would be glad to accept it

Comment: @Reyno thanks for the link. It seems to me like they all have the same specificity (they are all class selectors) and that's why in the end the order in which they appear in the generated CSS defines which one is applied.

Comment: Correct, if the specificity is the same it will look at the order that they appear in

Comment: @opensas No, I knew that, I was using it more as a general term. But I thought tailwind would give the same behavior as when you would put it in an inline style. But I tried it and it isn't. So now I understand your question.

Comment: It seems to me like tailwind is just ordering them alphabetically, which can often produce undesired results. I guess they key take away is that we can not rely on overriding tailwind utilities, and should use something like tw-merge

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CBroe comment, I realized it all depends on the order in which tailwind classes appears in the generated CSS.

For [this example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/EDfCXFQ6z9)

```html
<div class="grid h-screen place-content-center bg-red-100">
  <div class="w-80 bg-red-300 py-8 px-8 p-2 px-20">Content</div>
</div>
```

tailwind generated these classes, in the following order:

```css
...
.p-2 {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.px-20 {
  padding-left: 5rem;
  padding-right: 5rem;
}

.px-8 {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.py-8 {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

So even though `p-2 px-20` appears last in `<div class="w-80 bg-red-300 py-8 px-8 p-2 px-20">Content</div>`, in the CSS file the last ones are `px-8` and `py-8`, which overrides them.